# Set authentication as true for the view of the control that performs the authentication in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, view

In the authentication control I have the following line to mark a user as authenticated in the system (after checking out the password):

```
FormsAuth.SignIn(userName, rememberMe);
```

and if I redirect, which is the standard behvaior, everything is ok. But if I show a view right away, the usual ways to check whether a user is authenticated:

```
Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
Request.IsAuthenticated
```

don't work. They say the user is not authenticate. How can I make the authentication effective immediately or is there another way to check that would allow me to find out when the user just logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FormsAuth.SignIn` is a function which is generated when you create a new ASP.NET MVC project from Visual Studio.

That function simply calls [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx), which according to the docs, sets the authentication cookie in the **response**.

This explains why it works if you redirect (because the client will play back the cookie in the subsequent request), but not right after the call.

Redirecting is the right/conventional way to do this, but if you absolutely insist on checking authentication before a redirect, then you could create an IsAuthenticated flag in session state and refer to that when checking.

Answer (score 0):

On your Controllers, you should be able to use the following to check if they're authenticated.

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

I would check to make sure that your AccountController is properly saving the Principal object as you move from page to page.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the FormsAuth.Signin or FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie, you can also set the User.Identity manually in your sign-in control when the sign-in code executes. As written above, the reason is because the FOrmsAuth.SignIn simply sets the authentication cookie to be picked up next time in the Request_OnAuthenticate event. (Which simply decodes the cookie and sets the HttpContext.User property)